# Negation not working with .equalsIgnoreCase()

Tags: java

I am trying to run a do...while while a condition is not met but for some reason my code keeps looping every time regardless of the value of the condition. I've checked my debugger and the value of the variable is correct and the conditions within the loop are met according to similar logic. For some reason the `!` doesn't work. Here is my code

```
do
  {
     if(isRaceHorse.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
     {
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of races your horse has been in >> ");
        numRaces = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your horse is named " + name + " it is a " + color + " horse born in " + birthYear + " and it has been in " + numRaces + " races.");
     }
     else if(isRaceHorse.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
     {
        System.out.println("Your horse is named " + name + " it is a " + color + " horse born in " + birthYear + ".");
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println("Please use Y for yes and N for no.");
        System.out.print("Is your horse a race horse? Enter Y for yes and N for no >> ");
        isRaceHorse = input.nextLine();
     }
  }while(!(isRaceHorse.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) || !(isRaceHorse.equalsIgnoreCase("n")));
```

Anybody have any ideas as to why this is not giving me what I want?

Comment: What do you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
!(isRaceHorse.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) || !(isRaceHorse.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
```

In English, this means the loop will continue as long as `isRaceHorse` is not equal to `"y"` **or** `isRaceHorse` is not equal to `"n"`.  Since it cannot be equal to both `"y"` and `"n"` at the same time, I'm pretty certain you want to use `&&` instead:

```
!isRaceHorse.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !isRaceHorse.equalsIgnoreCase("n")
```

Comment: Thanks, I got my logic backwards. I appreciate it!

Comment: Sure thing mate.